# Scala how to multiply a RowMatrix and BDM

Tags: scala, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm trying to see an effective way to get this accomplish in Scala.

1. I have a `RowMatrix` and a BDM
2. I would like to crete a function multiply (Matrix Multiplication)
3. My approach is to get the Row of `RowMatrix` A and then convert to `Matrix` and then Multiply it with B

I'm trying to get the type to `Matrix` but I'm lost.

```
A.rows.map{case (X) => convertToMatrix(X) * B }
```

Is there a function where I can call to convert the row I got from A to a Matrix?? Secondly can I multiply it with B directly to get `A.multiply(B)` ?

I'm trying to multiply the row from A to the matrix B but I'm getting this error:

```
scala> A.rows.map{case (v) => toBreezeVector(v).multiply(B)}
<console>:41: error: value multiply is not a member of breeze.linalg.Vector[Double]
```

Answer (score 0):

Scala has a good library called [ScalaNLP](http://www.scalanlp.org/) which provides DenseMatrix (It is not BreezeDenseMatrix)class for matrix operations. ScalaNLP can use BLAS native realisations to perform matrix multiplication.
It is realy fast.

Comment: I decided to  just convert the BDM to a Matrix using breeze and use the matrix multiply method